# How to output additional info from my XCUITest to Fastlane log

Tags: swift, jenkins, xctest, fastlane, xcuitest

I use fastlane to wrap my XCUITests, but got from fastlane only some log:

```
[18:04:56]: ▸ All tests
[18:04:56]: ▸ Test Suite GUITests.xctest started
[18:04:56]: ▸ GT01FirstLaunchUITest
[18:05:11]: ▸ ✓ testFirstLaunch (15.405 seconds)
[18:07:59]: ▸ GT06CreateRequestUITest
[18:08:30]: ▸ ✓ test01LaunchAuth (30.513 seconds)
[18:09:35]: ▸ ✓ test02CreateRequestCheckAll (65.524 seconds)
```

But I want get more verbose log:
For example as:

```
▸ GT01FirstLaunchUITest
▸ ✓ testFirstLaunch (15.405 seconds)
- onboarding are exists
- check is right
- and so on
```

I know about Xcode standard log for ui-tests: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GG-atkebwuxkjajqjcjvgrduoiajkoi/Logs/Test/Run-GGUITests-2019.07.22_18-22-40-+0300.xcresult

Its very useful but more for debug not for use in CI

- How I can do this?
- How I can output smth to fastlane log?
- What are needed add to my XCUITests on swift for any print additional info to fastlane ?

Thanks anyway

Comment: I don't think you can do it. The best way to obtain something quite similar is to chunk your test in multiple smaller tests. So, `testFirstLaunch` will become `testOnboardingExists` and `testCheckIsRight` for example.

Comment: @cesarmarch thanks a lot. 
I thinked so also. But its sometimes hard to realize. 
Cos, I should start every next testFunc() from launch app.

Comment: and I should pass many screen always in every test for get my screen from first test  for example. 
Every next test even in one class restart my app.
Can I change this settings maybe?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I delete app.launch() from setUp() method 
And put this method to function testFirst() and app not restarting between tests. 
Very nice. 
But anyway, interesting to know 
Is it possible  output from Xcode to fastlane or log of Xcode?

Comment: Nice, it was what I advise you to do. Glad it works !